# Кроссдоменные куки

Tags: домен, php, cookie, yii

Всем доброго времени суток. Есть проблема в yii с куками на поддоменах: в /protected/config/main.php прописано

```
'session' => array (
    'autoStart'=>true,
    'cookieParams' => array('domain' => '.mydomain'),
),

'user'=>array(
    'allowAutoLogin'=>true,
    //'identityCookie' => array('domain' => '.mydomain'),
),
```

При этом на каждом поддомене приходится логиниться по отдельности. Если раскомментить `'identityCookie' => array('domain' => '.mydomain'),` - залогиниться не получается вовсе. Сервер - openserver под Виндой. Как настроить куки правильно?
Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Ну а в devtools хрома смотрели на параметры куки? Что там пишет то? Если она вообще не создается, то заголовки нужно анализировать.

Comment: Создаются на `sub.mydomain` (`mydomain`) или не создаются вовсе.  
Set-Cookie: PHPSESSID=6buq6012o1nqg109gb6g1t9lt4; path=/; domain=.mydomain

Comment: Мало информации. (у меня был проект, где на авторизация проходила на одном поддомене, а использовалась она на остальных. Все прекрасно работало, за исключением проблем с чтением из других поддоменов)

- После авторизации на этом поддомене, вы авторизованы?
- Что написано в devtool браузера?
- Как вы читаете куку на других поддоменах? (suhosin не мешает?)